# Expo router default index page not working

Tags: android, typescript, react-native, expo, expo-router

I'm creating an app with expo 50 and expo router, this is my file structure:

[image]

In my sign-in file i have a simple form that handle this function:

```
  const signInWithPassword = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);

    const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithPassword({
      email: username,
      password: password,
    });

    if (error) {
      Alert.alert(error.message);
      setIsLoading(false);
    } else {
      await signIn(data.session.access_token, data.session.refresh_token);
      setIsLoading(false);
      router.replace("");
    }
  };
```

after that i want to return to home page, this is my app/_layout.tsx

```
import type { Theme } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { DarkTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { Stack } from "expo-router";
import { SafeAreaProvider } from "react-native-safe-area-context";
import { AuthProvider } from "../context/AuthContext";
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";

import { useColorScheme } from "react-native";

export default function Root() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  const DefaultTheme: Theme = {
    dark: false,
    colors: {
      primary: "rgb(0, 122, 255)",
      background: "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
      card: "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
      text: "rgb(28, 28, 30)",
      border: "rgb(216, 216, 216)",
      notification: "rgb(255, 59, 48)",
    },
  };

  return (
    <ThemeProvider value={colorScheme === "dark" ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}>
      <AuthProvider>
        <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <SafeAreaProvider>
            <Stack initialRouteName="(app)">
              <Stack.Screen name="sign-in" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
              <Stack.Screen name="sign-up" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
              <Stack.Screen
                name="activity/note"
                options={{ headerShown: false }}
              />
              <Stack.Screen
                name="activity/feelings"
                options={{ headerShown: false }}
              />
              <Stack.Screen name="(app)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
              <Stack.Screen name="modal" options={{ presentation: "modal" }} />
            </Stack>
          </SafeAreaProvider>
        </GestureHandlerRootView>
      </AuthProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Inside (app) folder i have my _layout with Tabs.Screen

```
import { Redirect, Tabs } from "expo-router";
import { useAuth } from "../../context/AuthContext";
import { useColorScheme } from "react-native";

import { SimpleLineIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons';

export default function AppLayout() {
  const { isLoading, userToken } = useAuth();
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();
  // You can keep the splash screen open, or render a loading screen like we do here.
  /*
  if (isLoading) {
    return <Text>Loading...</Text>;
  }
  */

  // Only require authentication within the (app) group's layout as users
  // need to be able to access the (auth) group and sign in again.
  if (!userToken) {
    // On web, static rendering will stop here as the user is not authenticated
    // in the headless Node process that the pages are rendered in.
    return <Redirect href="/sign-in" />;
  }

  // This layout can be deferred because it's not the root layout.
  return (
    <Tabs
      screenOptions={{
        tabBarActiveTintColor: "#2f95dc",
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarShowLabel: false,
      }}
      initialRouteName="index"
    >
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="index"
        options={{
          title: "Home",
          tabBarIcon(props) {
            return <AntDesign name="home" size={24} color={colorScheme === "light" ? (props.focused ? "black" : "gray") : (props.focused ? "white" : "#ced4da")} />
          }
        }}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="metrics"
        options={{
          title: "Metrics",
          tabBarIcon(props) {
            return <SimpleLineIcons name="graph" size={24} color={colorScheme === "light" ? (props.focused ? "black" : "gray") : (props.focused ? "white" : "#ced4da")} />
          }
        }}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="expert"
        options={{
          title: "Expert",
          tabBarIcon(props) {
            return <AntDesign name="staro" size={24} color={colorScheme === "light" ? (props.focused ? "black" : "gray") : (props.focused ? "white" : "#ced4da")} />
          }
        }}
      />
      <Tabs.Screen
        name="settings"
        options={{
          title: "Impostazioni",
          tabBarIcon(props) {
            return <AntDesign name="setting" size={24} color={colorScheme === "light" ? (props.focused ? "black" : "gray") : (props.focused ? "white" : "#ced4da")} />
          },
        }}
      />
    </Tabs>
  );
}
```

The problem is when i complete login in **development enviroments** all works correcty but in android play store build, after login **the splash screen is shown and not the index page**